# Event triggered by bookmark drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to capture the event triggered by dragging and dropping a bookmark onto the window, preferably in all browsers.  What I actually need is the target url of the bookmark. `onbeforeunload` does get triggered, but the event has no information about the target URL and I can't stop the page from loading it either.  `mouseup` also does not work.

The `FileReader` API seems viable, but I'm not sure whether it's appropriate.  Ideally this would also work in at least IE9 (which does not support `FileReader`).

Comment: Are you running from within the browser's chrome or within a page displayed by the chrome?

Comment: My initial response is, "That doesn't seem possible". That's userland, and until the page loads, you're not able to access what the browser is doing. Do you have a demo of the overall functionality you're trying to create that gets you almost there?

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution to part one of this problem, but I myself would like some help with the second part of it, so if this serves as a bump for your question it'd be much appreciated.

NOTE: Most of this is based off of my personal experience, so I'll make notes about compatibility before we get too far in.

- The [`drop` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/drop_event) is supported on Microsoft Edge 12+, and has a field, [`dataTransfer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DragEvent/dataTransfer), that contains information about the element being dragged/dropped. This field was added to IE in is always `null`, and for that reason I won't be talking about a solution I found for it. From the timing of your post, it seems like you're using the latest Microsoft browser, which means that the features I talk about below will be supported.

The first event you'll want to take a look at is `drop`. This event, fairly logically, is an event that is fired when you drop an element onto a page, be it a file, another element, or in our case, a bookmark.

The second event, rather confusingly, is [`dragover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/dragover_event). For some unknown reason, suppressing default behavior of the `drop` event on its own does not seem to completely negate the effect of going to a new webpage, instead redirecting me (using Chrome 94) to about:blank#blocked in a new tab, which might interfere with UX.

The `files` attribute of `dataTransfer` for the `drop` event usually contains the information about the data that is being transferred, and as I have experimented with, I've gotten this data from it:

```js
{
  items: DataTransferItemList {0: DataTransferItem {'kind': 'string', 'type': 'text/plain'}, 1: DataTransferItem {'kind': 'string', 'type': 'text/uri-list'}, length: 2},
  types: ['text/plain', 'text/uri-list'],
  files: FileList {length: 0}
}
```

I'm rather frustrated by the fact that `files` contains no data, and it's currently got me stuck to a point where I can't get any further. I'll see if I remember to post back here when/if it gets fixed, but until then, there's another thing I'd like to point out.

On Windows computers, internet shortcuts are actually small files with the `.url` extension. So, it's possible to obtain both a name for a site and its address if the user simply drags in a shortcut from their homepage. My code for getting the data is below.

```js
element.addEventListener('drag', function(event)) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // in case you haven't put this in already; having multiple has
  // the same effect as one
  let shortcutFile = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
  // This assumes the user is only dragging a single file, but it can be
  // expanded to others by simply detecting the extension of the file.
  let fileName = shortcutFile.name;
  let fileLines = fileContent.split('\n');
  // the last line of the file has a pattern that looks like this:
  //   URL=<url to site>
  // this is what i'm going to be using to get the address.
  // 
  // the better solution to the first index below would be to use
  // Array.prototype.at(-1), however doing so would require a polyfill
  // on all versions of Opera, IE, and Safari, not to mention that even somewhat
  // recent browsers don't have this method implemented.

  let siteUrl = fileLines[fileLines.length - 1].match(/(?<=URL=)/)[0];
  
  // going to use one of my favorite JS features here: object destructuring!
  // it's not supported in some older browsers, or in IE at all, but it's a VERY
  // cool feature nonetheless, so I use it when i really shouldn't a lot of the time
  // 
  // i know stuff is supposed to be cross-compatible but what's the point
  // in browsers getting new APIs/interfaces like this if you don't use
  // them?
  return {fileName, siteUrl};
  
  // oh yeah explanation of how it works
  // it's basically the same thing as saying {fileName: fileName, siteUrl: siteUrl}
  // looks very nice right?
}
```

Hope this information and workaround helps, and that the exact issue we both have gets resolved!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! You have to use this method to get the actual URL: [DataTransfer.getData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/getData). Try putting

`console.log(e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain"));`

into your "drop" event - it shows the URL for both Firefox and Chrome.